# Python - TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Tags: python

I get this error when I try to run my code. Please help, and explain what it's trying to say!

This program is meant to find a persons ballot paper vote preferences (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc) for each candidate, and remove their first preference. That first preference is replaced by `99999`, to make it easier for me.

Error:

```
ERROR CODE: minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Code:

```
def countVotes(voteList):
candidatePreferences = []

for vote in voteList:
    minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
    candidatePreferences.append(minIndex)
    vote[minIndex] = 99999
return candidatePreferences
```

Value of `vList` (after calling countVotes function first time):

```
[[99999, '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['4', '2', '5', '3', 99999], [99999, '3', '2', '5', '4'], [99999, '2', '4', '3', '5'], [99999, '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['2', 99999, '3', '5', '4'], [99999, '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['3', '5', '2', '4', 99999], [99999, '4', '5', '2', '3'], ['5', 99999, '4', '3', '2'], ['3', '2', '5', '4', 99999], ['3', 99999, '2', '5', '4'], ['2', '5', 99999, '4', '3'], ['3', '2', 99999, '4', '5'], ['4', '5', '3', 99999, '2'], [99999, '5', '4', '3', '2'], [99999, '5', '3', '4', '2'], ['2', 99999, '4', '3', '5'], ['4', 99999, '2', '5', '3']]
```

Calling the function (second time):

```
cp = countVotes(vList)

minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: Don't try to compare a string to an integer.

Comment: `min(vote)` when you have a list of mixed types.

Comment: I dont have a list of mixed types do I?? vList contains all integers

Comment: `'3'` is a string.  `3` is an integer.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python cannot order `str` values and `int` values together.
In your example `99999` is an `int` value while all the other values are `str` values.

Comment: Thankyou I did not see that

Comment: nit: `Integer` and `String` in inline code formatting is off for Python: `int` and `str` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think is this line  minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
You are trying to find min on a string list. so what you can

```
def countVotes(voteList):
    candidatePreferences = []

    for vote in voteList:
         vote = map(int, vote)
         minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
         candidatePreferences.append(minIndex)
         vote[minIndex] = 99999
   return candidatePreferences
```

After converting string list to Int list you can perform min operation.
Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it fixed the error:

```
def countVotes(voteList):
    candidatePreferences = []

    for vote in voteList:
        minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
        candidatePreferences.append(minIndex)
        vote[minIndex] = '99999'
    return candidatePreferences

vList = [['1', '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['4', '2', '5', '3', '1'], ['1', '3', '2', '5', '4'], ['1', '2', '4', '3', '5'], ['1', '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['2', '1', '3', '5', '4'], ['1', '3', '4', '5', '2'], ['3', '5', '2', '4', '1'], ['1', '4', '5', '2', '3'], ['5', '1', '4', '3', '2'], ['3', '2', '5', '4', '1'], ['3', '1', '2', '5', '4'], ['2', '5', '1', '4', '3'], ['3', '2', '1', '4', '5'], ['4', '5', '3', '1', '2'], ['1', '5', '4', '3', '2'], ['1', '5', '3', '4', '2'], ['2', '1', '4', '3', '5'], ['4', '1', '2', '5', '3']]
cp = countVotes(vList)
print(str(cp))

output:
[0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert string elements to integer.You can use python [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function to convert all the list elements to integer

```
def countVotes(voteList):
    candidatePreferences = []
    for vote in voteList:
        vote = list(map(int, vote)) # add this line to the code to convert string elements to integer
        minIndex = int(vote.index(min(vote)))
        candidatePreferences.append(minIndex)
        vote[minIndex] = 99999
    return candidatePreferences
```